# Autofixture, expected behavior?

Tags: autofixture

Having a test similar to this:

```
public class myClass
{
    public int speed100index = 0;
    private List<int> values = new List<int> { 200 };

    public int Speed100
    {
        get
        {
            return values[speed100index];
        }
    }
}
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var sut = fixture.Create<myClass>();
        Assert.AreEqual(sut.Speed100, 200);
    }
}
```

Would have expected this to work, but I can see why it's not. But how do I argue, that this is not a problem with AutoFixture, but a problem with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoFixture is giving you feedback about the design of your class. The feedback is, you should follow a more object-oriented design for this class.

Protect your private state, to prevent your class from entering an inconsistent state.

You need to make the `speed100index` field, private, to ensure it remains consistent with the `values` List.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I see if I run debugger on your test:

[image: Debugging]

Autofixture assigns a random number to `speed100index` field because it is public, and in your array there is nothing at point 53 (from my screenshot)

If you set `speed100index` to be private, Autofixture will not re-assign the number and your test will pass.